# package does not exist erro

Tags: java

I get the error mentioned below when i try to run my code. What it screams for ?

The errors i get at the moment

```
Error:(5, 34) java: package com.fasterxml.jackson.core does not exist
Error:(8, 38) java: package com.fasterxml.jackson.databind does not exist
Error:(15, 17) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ObjectMapper
  location: class Main
```

Comment: `package does not exist`... Your error is that you are missing libraries in your classpath.

Comment: Where did you copy this code from? Did you miss that Jackson needed to be added separately to your project?

Comment: What about the funcyionality, how it could be implemented ? that if i write a date i get the other information ?

Comment: All the JSON values are Strings. You cannot get a `Date` unless you explicitly parse the String

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the library in your classpath. If you use maven or gradle you can simply add it as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

As said above, you need to add the Jackson library before you can import it in your project. If you have a maven project, simply visit the library page [Jackson-databind repo. page](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.8) and copy/paste the XML into your .POM file.

Otherwise, if it is a regular java project, use to Ctr+Alt+Shift+S to visit project structure on IntelliJ IDEA, click on libraries, and then click + to add groupId, artifactId, VersionId in the text input popup. See the example below.
[Manually add the library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upFev.png)

Note that versionID may differ depending on when you visit the page